# Enable the input of a cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of an input cell to pink if the user types an incorrect key. I can get it to change but I can't reset the color after they click the cell. I have tried using .prop("disabled", false). What am I missing here?

```
function setUnitField(a) {
$(function () {
    var tbl = $(document.getElementById('21.125-mrss-cont-none-content'));
    var str1 = 'Each';
    var str2 = 'Dozen';
    var str3 = 'Foot';
    var str4 = 'Us Gallon';


    tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find("input[name$='8#if']").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                if ($(this).val() == 'EA') {
                    $(this).val(str1);
                    $(this).css("background-color", "");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
                }

                if ($(this).val() == 'DZ') {
                    $(this).val(str2);

                } 
                if ($(this).val() == 'Ft') {
                    $(this).val(str3);

                } 
                if ($(this).val() == 'GAL') {
                    $(this).val(str4);

                }           
            }
        });
    });



});
```

}

```
<input id="grid#21.125#1,8#if" ct="I" type="text" maxlength="3" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="lsTblEdf3 lsTblEdf3NoEllipsis" value="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="grid#21.125#1,8#if" onfocus="cellClick('grid#21.125#1,8','true');" onkeypress="cellKeyPress('grid#21.125#1,8',event);" oninput="setCacheValue(this); setUnitField(this);">
```

Comment: You'll need to post a complete example for anyone to be able to properly help you. Things such as the HTML and the rest of your associated JS at a minimum I would suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

```js
var str1 = 'Each';
var str2 = 'Dozen';
var str3 = 'Foot';
var str4 = 'Us Gallon';
$('table').find('tr').each(function () {
  $(this).find("input[name$='8#if']").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13){ 
      if ($(this).val() == 'EA') {
          $(this).val(str1);
          $(this).css("background-color", "");
      } 
      else if ($(this).val() == 'DZ') {
          $(this).css("background-color", "");
          $(this).val(str2);

      } 
      else if ($(this).val() == 'Ft') {
          $(this).css("background-color", "");
          $(this).val(str3);

      } 
      else if ($(this).val() == 'GAL') {
          $(this).css("background-color", "");
          $(this).val(str4);
      }
      else {
          $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
      }
    }
    else {
          $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="grid#21.125#1,8#if" ct="I" type="text" maxlength="3" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="lsTblEdf3 lsTblEdf3NoEllipsis" value="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="grid#21.125#1,8#if"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want the color to be normal while typing?

Comment: Please approve my answer then.

Comment: It works but it's highlighting every input, not just the ones that are wrong.I added more of the code.

Comment: Can you add html?

Comment: Added the input element

Comment: As there are some other functions attached in the element, I have modified the code with previous input. Please check in the snippet.

Comment: Try it now. I have used your input html except all the functions that I don't have.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!